# Life support: fraction of launch weight?

Tags: launch, life-support

What fraction of launch payload mass for a manned (or animal'd) mission is attributable to life support equipment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fraction of launch payload of a ECLSS (environmental control and life support system) depends on a number of factors. The two most important factors to consider are:

1. **What type of systems make up the ECLSS?** Are your systems completely regenerative or do they require consumables? Most likely the system is a combination of the two. A fully regenerative system wouldn't require extra consumables and thus would result in a lower overall subsystem mass.
2. **What is the mission profile and how does this influence the safety margin of the ECLS system?** All human spaceflight missions are designed within a certain safety margin and thus require redundant systems, extra margins with regard to the consumables, and spare parts to fix the systems if/when they break. This is all to say that a mission to LEO which has the ability for a quick abort might allow for a lower safety margin. Such a mission could quickly abort if the ECLSS fails irreparably using an escape vehicle (i.e. Soyuz on the ISS). A mission to Mars does not have the ability for a quick abort and thus the safety margin and the ECLSS mass must increase.

Larsen and Pranke's text *Human Spaceflight* gives a rule of thumb of **8% dry mass** for the ECLSS. This includes pressurizing, oxygen supply, controlling and revitalizing the atmosphere, and active thermal control. This was found via extrapolation from NASA mission data.

Comment: The duration of the misson and the number of humans or animals also influence the necessary fraction of payload.